# How Do I redirect to php file with Htaccess

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is there a way to redierct a url to a php file based on one part of the url.

For example I have a url -

`http://www.website.org/Cat/89/Diamond-Wedding-Rings.htm`

I will have a few different of these urls. I wish to redirect all the pages with /Cat/ to a php file which will pull the Id and display the category and products.

in my htaccess I have

```
RewriteRule ^Cat/([0-9]+)/(.*)\.htm category.php?cat_id=$1&title=$2 [NC,L]
```

I'm not getting a 404 because the cms system redirects to the homepage if the page is not found.

I'm a complete noob when it comes to htaccess and I'm basing this on some of the existing rules in the htaccess which do something similar. I don't really need the title part it's really just the ID.

Comment: It's the companys own CMS. It's only used by this company.

Comment: Try opening this URL in your browser: `http://category.php?cat_id=89&title=Diamond-Wedding-Rings` and see if it loads or not.

Comment: Yes it loads and has the content i need

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is the id then this will work

```
RewriteRule ^Cat/([0-9]+)/(.*) category.php?cat_id=$1
```

Comment: You need to escape dot with \ in a regex.

Comment: Tried this and it did not work. Same thing happens, it redirects to homepage.

Comment: Your .htaccess file is in your root directory correct? Do you have any other re-write rules in your htaccess file?

Comment: Yes htaccess is in the root and there are other rules there.

Comment: And what about other rules in the htaccess file?